# AWS Cognito : User showing confirmed even when email / phone is not verified

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I Just realised that i have "**few**"  users in my userpool with Confirmed status, even when these particular users have not verified their email or phone.

How can this happen? these are self signed up user. which means they have to verify their phone or email in order to get confirmed.

I cannot even reproduce the issue.
If i signup a new user now, i can see the unconfirmed status for this user, once i verify my phone using otp. it changes its status to confirmed. which is all correct.

I am wondering how those few users managed to get confirmed status without verifying. Has anyone faced similar issue like this?

[image: user showing confirmed status who is actually not confirmed]

Comment: I've only seen it when user is confirmed by either admin or cognito sign up trigger.